# How to upload video in Shopify

Tags: javascript, html, shopify

I want to upload video in my shopify store my code has for loop

```
   <div class="product-slider-show">
      <div class="owl-carousel">
         {% for image in product.images %}
         <div class="swiper-product-image"> 
            <a class="cloud-zoom-gallery sub-image" id="product-image-options-" href="{{ image.src  | img_url: 'master' }}" title="{{ featured_img_alt }}"
               rel="useZoom: 'product-cloud-zoom', smallImage: '{{ image.src | img_url: 'master' }}'" data-pos="{{ forloop.index }}">
            <img {% if settings.lazyloading_enable %} class="lazyload" data-{% endif %}src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'master' }}" title="{{ featured_img_alt }}" alt="{{ featured_img_alt }}" />
            </a>
         </div>
         {% endfor %}
      </div>
   </div>
```

When I add video html to this code, video shows up next to each pictures.

What code should I use in this for loop, so that the video can appear alone at the end?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone else is having this problem. This code was my solution

```
{% for image in product.images %}
{% if forloop.first == true %}
<figure>            
   <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" class="product_variant_image">
</figure>
{% else %}
<figure>            
   <img src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">
</figure>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% for media in product.media %}
{% if media.media_type == 'video' %}
{{ media | video_tag: controls: true, preload: true, image_size: "768x" }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).